# Embed raw html from github in another website

Tags: html, github

I'm wondering how I can embed an html file found in github on an external website using standard html. For instance, I know that this can be done for html that has already been rendered in gitpages using `iframes`, but is there a way to do the same for a raw html that has not been rendered with gitpages?

Some example randomly chosen: I can render the [404 page here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipasdage/) using `iframes` because it was already rendered with gitpages, but how can I do the same for the source [html found here](https://github.com/whatwg/html/blob/main/404.html)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it with some workaround.

1. Get the url to the raw html.
   [image: Github Raw]
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/whatwg/html/main/404.html
2. Bypass X-Frame Limitation with this [library](https://github.com/niutech/x-frame-bypass).

```css
.frame {
    position:fixed; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    right:0; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    border:none; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@ungap/custom-elements-builtin"></script>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/x-frame-bypass"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe class="frame" is="x-frame-bypass" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/whatwg/html/main/404.html"></iframe>
</body>
<script>
</script>
</html>
```